# How to input text into text field with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, input, textfield, getparameter

I have a form on a wordpress site with a text field for an email adress which looks like this:

```
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email"><label>Email</label><input class="tnp-email" type="email" name="ne" required></div>
```

I can get the email address from a get parameter (www.domain.com/?email=test@mail.com) like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

function getUrlParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
    var urlparameter = defaultvalue;
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
        urlparameter = getUrlVars()[parameter];
        }
    return urlparameter;
}

var emailtxt = getUrlParam('email','');
```

How can I fill the text field with **emailtxt**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the value of the input field (`HTMLInputElement.value = "value"`).

```
document.querySelector("input[name=ne]").value = getUrlParam('email','');
```

```html
<div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email"><label>Email</label><input class="tnp-email" type="email" name="ne" required></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

function getUrlParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
    var urlparameter = defaultvalue;
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
        urlparameter = getUrlVars()[parameter];
    }
    return urlparameter;
}

var emailtxt = getUrlParam('email','');
 console.log(emailtxt);
document.querySelector('input[name=ne]').value = emailtxt;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I address the correct input field? It doesn't have an ID because I created it with a plugin.

Comment: You could use the `class` or `name` attributes

Comment: @user363808 You can use the name of the input field. `document.querySelector('input[name=ne]')`

Comment: Note that `querySelector` in this case will get the first `input`.

Comment: It works now. I'm such an idiot. I had my javascript code in the header. Of course it can't work if the form isnt loaded yet I feel so embarres. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user363808 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try DOM id selector:

```
<input class="tnp-email" type="email" name="ne" id="yourId" required>

document.getElementById("yourId").innerHTML = "Your text";
```

Comment: Thanks but I sadly can't add an ID to the textfield because it is generated by a plugin. Is here a way to use the class instead?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to be careful with that because class selector will return all class name matching DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM class name selector like this:

```
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tnp-email");
 x[0].value = "Your value";
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either. I didn't manage to use getElement so far with any of the suggested methods.